# Where to get TwitterCore from?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am trying to implement [Twitter Login](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter-login) into my `Android` application. Apparently `Twitter` uses [fabric](https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/overview) in their tutorials. I have tried to sign up for `fabric` but I got an e-mail saying

> Demand is high at the moment. You’re on the list, and we’ll reach out shortly — stay tuned!

**Is there a way to get those libraries I need to implement Twitter Login using [this tutorial](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter-login) or do I need to wait for them to decide when I can start using it?**

As a bonus question, does anyone know why they're doing this instead of giving us direct access to Fabric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm from Developer Relations team at Twitter.

We are processing all the requests to Fabric as fast as we can. Your request will be approved soon. Sorry for the inconvenience.

> Is there a way to get those libraries I need to implement Twitter Login using this tutorial or do I need to wait for them to decide when I can start using it?

Currently there's no way to get the libraries because the onboarding process includes the automatic creation of app keys with the proper permissions and the keys needed by Crashlytics.

Regarding twitter4j mentioned by Justin. Despite the fact that it indeed work pretty well in Android apps, Twitter Kit implementation provides some optimizations such as built-in asynchronous calls.

Comment: Hemal got in touch and he is helping me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Hello sir, could you please help me out with my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190313/making-rest-api-calls-from-an-android-app-using-twitterapiclient-class) ... thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html). It is a pure java api that is compatible with Android. Twitter references it on their [Twitter Libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries) page.